# Import file on SAS Enterprise Guide

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I want to import a file in CSV format, stored on a local network drive to the SAS Enterprise Guide via code. How to make ?

Answer (score 0):

```
proc import 
        dbms=csv                    /* specify you load comma separated data */
        datafile="C:\temp\test.csv" /* fill in your data file                */
        out=TEST                    /* specify de dataset to load it to      */
        replace;                    /* so TEST will be replaced if it exists */

/*      getnames=no;            /*  only if your file does not have headers  */
run;
```